# How can I click an HTML input inside of a Bootstrap 4 input-group to fire a bound Angular event

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 input group that contains a prepended title and an input as shown:

```
    <div class="input-group" (click)="openDoc()">
      <div class="input-group-prepend input-group-prepend-split rounded-0">
          <label class="input-group-text rounded-0 bg-white">Name</label>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" value="{{_transaction.originalDoc?.name}}" disabled>
      <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0 link" value="{{_transaction.doc?.name}}" disabled>
   </div>
```

I want to have the event `(click)="openDoc()"` exist on the second input with the `value: {{_transaction.doc?.name}}`, but cannot get the event to fire unless it is on the wrapper input-group.  I assume that the element is blocking the input, but I cannot figure out a way to bypass this.

Is there a CSS method or Bootstrap workaround to allow me to do this?

Comment: Can you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) with your code to help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.  The issue was the disabled attribute on each of my inputs, and had nothing to do with Bootstrap or the wrapper div.

Removing the disabled attribute allowed the event to fire.

UPDATE: For anyone who has experienced this specific issue, it can be resolved by simply replacing the 'disabled' attribute on the input with 'readonly'.  The link in the input will become clickable, but the input is not editable.